# Редирект на другую страницу

Tags: php

привет.Увидел код

```
function redirect($url, $statusCode = 303)
{
   header('Location: ' . $url, true, $statusCode);
   die();
}
```

Что означает 2 и 3 параметр header?

Создал пример с Ajax:

```
function vote() {

 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('GET', 'sender.php', false);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;

    if (xhr.status != 200) {

      return;
    }

    alert(xhr.responseText);
  }

  xhr.send(null);
}
```

**sender.php**

```
function redirect($url, $statusCode = 303)
{
   header('Location: ' . $url, true, $statusCode);
   die();
}
redirect('http://vk.com');
echo 'true';
```

получил ошибку:

**NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Failure
xhr.send(null);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Есть документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php)

```
void header ( string $string [, bool $replace = true [, int $http_response_code ]] )
```

> **replace** Необязательный параметр
> replace определяет, надо ли заменять
> предыдущий аналогичный заголовок или
> заголовок того же типа. По умолчанию
> заголовок будет заменен, но если
> передать FALSE, можно задать несколько
> однотипных заголовков.
>
> **http_response_code** Принудительно
> задает код ответа HTTP. Следует
> учитывать, что это будет работать,
> только если строка string не является
> пустой.

Comment: Запрос вернет для нашей страници ошибку 303 и перейдет на URL?

Comment: вроде так и будет :)

Comment: Но зачем такое может понадобится?

Comment: в документации ниже есть комментарий пример, который это используют, и там на английском идет пояснение, что-то типо: Браузер запомнит (закеширует) текущий адрес как с этой ошибкой (или роботы от поисковиков).

Comment: Возможно неправильно вам передал перевод (пред. комментарий мой):

> The HTTP status code changes the way browsers and robots handle redirects, so if you are using header(Location:) it's a good idea to set the status code at the same time.  Browsers typically re-request a 307 page every time, cache a 302 page for the session, and cache a 301 page for longer, or even indefinitely.  Search engines typically transfer "page rank" to the new location for 301 redirects, but not for 302, 303 or 307. If the status code is not specified, header('Location:') defaults to 302.